# How do I get rid of this funny number at the top left of the screen?

Tags: diablo-iii, overwatch, framerate

In all blizzard games, I saw a number on top left of the screen. That happens only on blizzard games.

[image]
[image]

I think I must have set that up before because I want to know fps. Now I have a fast computer and the fps is locked at 60 anyway, I want to undo it. I have no idea how.

Comment: That is likely the framerate that your game is running at.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's MSI AfterBurner, see if you got that open.

Comment: yes and I don't want it to be shown. I know it's 60 alraedy

Comment: what is AMD afterburner? It only happens on blizzard games.

Comment: MSI AfterBurner is a program. It may have came with your computer.

Comment: Try ctrl+shift+r

Comment: My bad it's MSI afterburner

Comment: Check if Fraps isn't running either

Answer (score 6):

While I can't say which program is adding the *On-Screen Display* for FPS (*Frames per Second*), I can confirm that it's not coming from Overwatch/D3. (Or the Blizzard launcher for that matter.)

The font that's being used seems like it's coming from **MSI Afterburner** or a program that uses the Afterburner software.  MSI Afterburner is a GPU  monitoring software that enables the user to do more things with their video cards. These include making straight-from-source screen shots, recording desktop/rendered video, and overclocking one's GPU.

Since this is the first time you've seen it on your machine, I assume you've recently downloaded some new software.  In particular, check the new program for "**Overlay**" or "**On Screen Display**" options.

Here's an example from my PC and settings. Notice that the display doesn't match the font of the game itself. Once you can find the program that's interacting with your games, you'll usually find the *On-Screen Display* option as a box you can uncheck.

[image: Beglitched with OSD of FPS]

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem.

It's overwolf. An unrelated software to capture stuffs.

I turned it off and it's fixed.

Comment: You can also disabe displaying of fps in the Overwolf settings. This might be helpful if you still want to use its features